# Skip stages in Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am skipping jenkins stages by implementing below code, its working fine but if we check in BlueOcean it shows three nodes like

checkout --> precheck --> post

I want to put precheck conditions in build stage and then if condition meet it skips rest of  stages

```
stages {
        stage('PreChecks') {
              when {
                beforeAgent true
                allOf {
                    not { changelog '.*skip' }
                    not { changeRequest author: 'release' }
                }
             }

            stages {
                stage('build') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'I am building '+scm.branches[0].name+' branch.'
                    }
                }

                stage('itest') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Testing..'
                    }
                }

                stage('deploy') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Deploying....'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want Blue Ocean to visually show the stages were skipped, then you need to make use of a `return` within the `when`. Functionally, as you noted, your code is achieving your goal.

Comment: how i can use return? any suggestion? or i have to do scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old post, but for anyone else coming in. The answer is to use "when"
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when